# Book where half the protagonist's body was replaced with cybernetics

Tags: story-identification, books, cyborg

I'm trying to remember the name of a sci-fi book that would have come out before 2000.

Because of an injury, half the main character's body has been replaced with cybernetics.  The only specific thing I remember is that they were imperfect, making running very difficult as the robot half was significantly better. There may also have been a major character who was a good friend to the main character and he was surprised to find they had a sex change to female.

Anyone have any idea what this was?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like the character Xris in the "[Mag Force](https://www.goodreads.com/series/50369-mag-force-7)" series by Margaret Weis. Xris used to be a governement agent but was caught in an explosion that he believed his partner set him up for. The result was that half his body was replaced with cybernetics, he then became a mercenary and took various jobs all over the galaxy but all the while searched for his old partner and when he found him the partner had changed sex to a woman. I cant remember which of the trilogy he finds his partner in (I think its number 2) but below is a list of the series and blurbs.

1. Knights of the Black Earth (1995)
   A group of mercenaries led by a freelance cyborg becomes involved in a plot to assassinate the galactic king.
2. Robot Blues (1996)
   This follow up to "The Knights of the Black Earth" has Xris Cyborg and his Mag Force 7 mercenaries crossing swords with the powerful Hung crime syndicate.
3. Hung Out (1998)
   When their cyborg leader, Xris, is jailed on a trumped-up charge of murder, the Mag Force 7 team realizes that they've become pawns in a treacherous game. At the core of the conspiracy is the ultra-secret Hung Syndicate, the most savage and corrupt criminal organization in the history of the galaxy. The Syndicate has big plans for planet Del Sol, but they've made one big mistake: leaving Xris and his crew alive to smash and blast their way to the truth.

Comment: It was the first one in which he found out his partner (the man/woman) was still alive, and Xris (pronounced Chris) was the one to hire his own team to take him/her out.